# Moonlight Sonata 3rd movement bar 20-23 left-hand technique

Tags: piano, beethoven, moonlight-sonata

My question is what technique should I focus on. In bar 20, I am using the tremolo, but in the passage of the chord there are 2 doubts: do I need to keep finger 1 pressed D # while I bring the other fingers to the next chord or should I move it up first to make the passage later? The other question, is in bars 21 and 22, I must shake between the fingers of the extremities (finger 1/5 in bar 21, finger 1/4 in bar 22) while the central finger just strums, or I must keep my wrist without oscillation (or with very little oscillation) while just typing as keys?
[image: Moonlight Sonata 3rd Mov. bar 20-23]

Answer (score 2):

Starting in 21 with that fast Alberti bass, most if not all teachers will recommend rotating your wrist to alternate between finger 1 and the lower fingers. Even the finger playing the middle note should be supported by wrist rotation. Josh Wright very recently posted an audio-only lesson on this on YouTube:

For the alternating bass 8th notes in most of measures 1-20, I would have a little wrist rotation combined with a slight left right motion of the arm so you don’t have to stretch the fingers too much.

With a piece like this you really should find a competent teacher even if you only have a lesson once in a while. Not all teachers require a weekly commitment.

Answer (score 2):

doesn't 5 and 2 make more sense for the first bar (and similar previous bars)? and 4121 for the second? but i'm not convinced there should be focus on wrist rotation. i think what i mean by this is: these LH passages are technically straightforward relative to the rest of the piece, so if they're offering difficulty then it questions the appropriateness of learning that piece.

i agree with the above comment about finding a competent teacher for a piece like this.